# How do I programmatically select from a select2 dropdown when using the tablesorter.filterformatter widget?

Tags: filter, jquery-select2, tablesorter

I would like to be able to programmatically select something from a dropdown, as in http://select2.github.io/select2/#programmatic. But the dropdown also seems to be generated (I didn't include it anywhere in the HTML) by the filterformatter widget, which I initialized with:

```
$('#client_table').tablesorter({
    theme: "blue",
    headers: {1: {sorter: 'types'}},
    widgets: ["filter", "zebra"],
    widgetOptions : {
        filter_formatter: {
            1 : function ($cell, indx) {
                return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2($cell, indx, {
                    closeOnSelect: false,
                    placeholder: "Select events",
                    allowClear: true,
                    match: false, // exact match only
                });
            },
```

What element do I call select2 on in this case? What are the values/data that I should be using (the thing I would like to select, for example, is the string APP_STATE).

Answer (score 0):

When select2 is applied to the table, the table cell gets a class name of `select2col0` where (`0` is the column zero-based index).

If you open [this demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-select2.html) and enter the following code in the console, it'll programmically set the value:

```
$('.select2col0').find('input').select2('val', ['abc']);
```